# Object in animation not rotating as expected

Tags: animation, keyframes

I'm trying to make a lamp do a jump with 360° salto. I inserted a keyframe halfway the jump with the object rotated 180°, expecting it would subsequently complete the rotation in the same direction. However, the object would reverse direction instead. Here's a clip: https://youtu.be/izNrIoVZnAg

I figured the reason was that the object chose the quickest direction to get in the rotation of the keyframe at the end of the jump. Hence I inserted another keyframe at around 3/4th of the jump with the lamp rotated a further 90° in the desired direction. However, it would still reverse direction. Another clip: https://youtu.be/0bsV_sZfzOc

Comment: Are there keyframes at the end of the animation as well? And do they by any chance specify the initial position?

Comment: Currently, the last keyframe of the animation is the object back in the original rotation. In between I have keyframe with object at a slight tilt for the landing. Between these landingframes and the one 3/4th of the salto the objects still rotates ~270° though.

Answer (score 1):

If the final keyframes put the object *back* in the starting position, **at 0°**, 
what happens is (for the first video):
- rotation starts in the required direction, from 0° to 180°
- on reaching the 180° keyframe, the rotation starts for the second part, *rotating from 180° to 0°*, **not** from 180° to 360° (which is what you wanted, but didn't specify).

Adding an extra keyframe at 270°, only means that the object will continue rotating until it reaches the 270°, and *then* go back to 0°.

For blender, 0° is **not** the same position as 360°, if you want to get a full rotation, your end position must be 360°.

Comment: I know, that's why I added another keyframe, with the object at roughly 270°, to nudge it in the right direction. However, the object still reverses direction and moves ~270° back to the landing position, instead of going ~90° forward, as you can see in the 2nd video.

Comment: If you want a full turn, your end position *must* be 360° (updated answer as well)

Comment: I don't really have objects in x degrees though. I'm rotating a bone for the animation and the values in the transform box are different.

Comment: Ah, switching from quaternion to euler does it. Thanks.